# Urgent Excel Help Needed Because of Test

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Does anyone know how I can lookup the values in one row in sheet 2 (see tables below) and compare this with all rows in sheet 1?

If any of the cell values in one row in sheet 2 equal the values in any of the rows in sheet 1 then I would like to return the values 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' for each cell that is being compared.

Additionally and perhaps most importantly I want to create a separate column which returns either TRUE if all of the values in one row within sheet 2 equal ALL of the values in any row in sheet 1 or else FALSE. Please note however, that the number of rows in sheet 2 is 200 and the number of rows in sheet 1 is 400. Therefore, the formula will need to search all 400 rows in sheet 1 to check if any of the rows (and all values contained within) in sheet 2 can be found in the 400 rows before determining whether to return TRUE or FALSE.

Your help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: (1) It is not Super User’s mission to be a formula- and/or script-writing service. What have you tried? You may get help if you show us what you’ve written so far and explain why you’re having trouble finishing the job. (2) You’ve tagged the question [vba] and [worksheet-function]. Which do you want? (Do you know the difference?) (3) You say “see tables below”, but then you don’t give any examples. You should post a textual representation of your data, as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table) site if you want. (Please don’t try to post screenshots.) Include the output data you expect from your input data (clearly identifying which is which) and give a clearer description of the computation you want Excel to do. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. P.S. Are you talking about a take-home test (from school)? We’re really not fond of doing people’s schoolwork for them.

Comment: Harvey, just to add to Scott's comment, Super User isn't a good place for urgent questions.  The site is a knowledge base of solutions intended to have long term value.  People contribute questions that are clearly asked so that others with a similar problem can recognize it.  Sometimes answers come in quickly, but they can also take a long time.  You can help things by making this as clear as possible, with what you have so far (screenshots, sample data and formulas, etc.).  But if this is something that won't be helpful to you unless you get a fast answer, the best source might be a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a test a down and dirty solution for the first part would be to use COUNTIF then use a special display to get true/false.

For the second part use a helper column and concatenate the columns, then use a similar formula to above.

As an aside, this is why I give prospective hires an excel test. It's a great way to see if they have general problem solving skills as well as specific excel formula/format knowledge.